# PostgreSQL Installation through source code. [all-src-recurse] Error 2

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am new to PostgreSQL. I am trying to install Postgres through source code. If I use some prebuilt binaries I am getting some dependency bugs. So I am using source code installation. While running the second step of Postgres installation i.e. `make` command I am getting these errors.

```
make[4]: *** [spgtextproc.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/usr/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend/access/spgist'
make[3]: *** [spgist-recursive] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/usr/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend/access'
make[2]: *** [access-recursive] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/postgresql-9.5.10/src/backend'
make[1]: *** [all-backend-recurse] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/postgresql-9.5.10/src'
make: *** [all-src-recurse] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo make install` fixed the error for me

Answer (score 0):

try these steps

```
./configure
gmake
su
gmake install
adduser postgres
mkdir /usr/local/pgsql/data
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
su - postgres
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data >logfile 2>&1 &
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb test
/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test
```

Comment: I wanted to install postgresql along with open ssl i have installed openssl also. Now when i run configure along with --with-openssl. Iam getting the error. as  error: library 'eay32' or 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL. How Should i proceed any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

While running the below command, I thought that src refers to the src directory(src) inside Postgres. And ran prefix to link it

```
./configure --prefix ~/postgres-12.0/src/
```

Here source refers to the directory where Postgres needs to be installed not the Postgres src directory.

Running the command like below solved it.

```
mkdir ~/any_directory
./configure --prefix ~/any_directory/
```